# how to copy "price" or "currency" value from dropdownlist with values(product, price, currency) to textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1.Question

**I want to copy the *price* and *currency* attached to the product, from dropdownlist.
How can this be done?**

2.This is my code:

```
 <select class="form-control" id="ProductList" onchange="copyValue()">
                <option>--- Select Product---</option>
                @foreach(var item in Model.PL)
                {
                    <option value="@item.ProdId">
                        <span style="min-width:60%;">@item.Name - </span>
                        <span style="width:20%;" id="price">@item.price</span>
                            <span style="width:20%;" id="currency">@item.currency</span>
                    </option>
                }
            </select>
<input class="form-control"id="pricecopy"/>
<input class="form-control"id="currencycopy"/>

<script>
    function copyValue() {

        var myvalue = document.getElementById('price', "option:selected").value;
        document.getElementById('pricecopy').value = myvalue;
var mycurrency = document.getElementById('currency', "option:selected").value;
        document.getElementById('currencycopy').value = mycurrency ;
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you to use custom attribute for *price* and *currency*.

**Change:**

```
<option value="@item.ProdId">
```

**To:**

```
<option value="@item.ProdId" price="@item.price" currency="@item.currency">
```

Then pass [*this*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to the function and use that to get the selected options attribute values.

**Please Note:** The attribute *Id* should not be unique in document, use *class* instead.

**Demo:**

```html
<select class="form-control" id="ProductList" onchange="copyValue(this)">
  <option>--- Select Product---</option>
  <option value="111" price=10 currency='$'>
        <span style="min-width:60%;">AAA</span>
        <span style="width:20%;" class="price">30</span>
        <span style="width:20%;" class="currency">$</span>
    </option>
    <option value="222" price=20 currency='₤'>
        <span style="min-width:60%;">BBB</span>
        <span style="width:20%;" class="price">20</span>
        <span style="width:20%;" class="currency">₤</span>
    </option>
</select>
<input class="form-control"id="pricecopy"/>
<input class="form-control"id="currencycopy"/>

<script>
  function copyValue(el) {
    let op = el.options[el.selectedIndex];
    let myvalue = el.value;
    let price = op.getAttribute('price');
    let currency = op.getAttribute('currency');
    document.getElementById('pricecopy').value = myvalue;
    document.getElementById('currencycopy').value = currency ;
  }
</script>
```